# What is the difference between [x,y] and [x,y,0]?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is there any difference at all, both in mathematical sense and physical sense.
My source of concern is that as in [x,y,0] the third coordinate is always 0 which would mean that all the movements of this vector is limited to (x,y) plane only so why should it be different from [x,y].

I understand that [x,y,0] has one extra dimension , but that seems to be the only difference that exist, and apart from that they are same in their behavior.

Am I missing out on some subtle issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can do a one-to-one mapping from a 2D plane to the subspace where $z=0$, you can *consider* them equal.

In other words, $(x,y)$ is a point in "any" 2D plane, and $(x,y,0)$ is a point in a 3D space which all fall on the plane where $z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Both systems are abstractly two-dimensional vector spaces - they are isomorphic. One is explicitly embedded in a three-dimensional space.

Taken as real vector spaces, and thinking geometrically, the existence of the third dimension in fact means that you can use the third dimension to prove things about the plane. ie you can construct three-dimensional figures to prove two-dimensional results. This sometimes makes life easier.

Comment: So is it mostly a mathematical convenience, and won't make much difference in real life application ?

Comment: It depends on what your application is and what you're trying to do. If you don't need to use the third dimension, you don't need a third coordinate.